# Print document value in mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to print the value for this JSON document in the mongo shell. Like a simple console output, without creating a new collection or document.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't realy see what you are asking. You can run that query in the mongo shell without any changes to it

Comment: you want use a console.log() on mongodbShell or print mongodb result like console.log output ?

Comment: You are using RoboMongo, currently you are in "tree mode" switch to "text mode" to see console output.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found a solution, by using `.forEach()` to apply a JavaScript method:

```
db.widget.find(
    { id : "4" }, 
    {quality_level: 1, _id:0}
).forEach(function(x) { 
    print(x.quality_level); 
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`db.collection.find()` returns a *cursor*.

There are a bunch of methods for the cursor object which can be used to get the cursor information, iterate, get and work with the individual documents from the query result (in the Mongo Shell). For example,

```
let result = db.widget.find( { id : "4" }, { quality_level: 1, _id: 0 } );
```

The methods `print`, `printjson` and `tojson` are useful for printing the query results assigned to a cursor and iterated over it, in the Mongo Shell.

In this particular example, each of the following statements will print the expected output:

```
    result.forEach( doc =>  print( doc.quality_level ) );
    result.forEach( doc =>  print( tojson(doc)) );
    result.forEach( printjson );
```

Note the query must be run each time the cursor is to be iterated, as the cursor gets closed after iterating thru it. But, one can use the `cursor.toArray()` method to get a *JavaScript array*, and iterate the array and work with the query result documents without running the query again.

*NOTES:*

- The `db.collection.findOne()` method returns a document (not a cursor).
- [Iterate a Cursor in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/index.html)
- [Mongo Shell cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/#js-query-cursor-methods)

Comment: In _mongo shell_: `db.collection.findOne()` prints the returned document in a well formatted JSON. To print the result (one or more documents) of `find()` in a formatted way, use `db.collection.find().pretty()`. These methods print all the fields of the document. To restrict the fields use _projection_ with the find methods.

Comment: print is not working for me, try print('Richard'), did not work

Comment: @RichardAguirre `print('Richard')` is a _valid_ statement in `mongo` shell. So is `print(123)` and `print([ 12, 34, 99, 1000]`. To print a JSON you use `printjson({ a: 65 })`.

Answer (score 1):

To print each document when returning a cursor:

```
db.widget.find().forEach(printjson);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.widget.findOne({"id":4},{quality_level:1,_id:0}).quality_level
```

The projection is not necessary for this to work, but it reduces the data which is to be transferred in case of a sharded collection.