# How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts? (mine does not work)

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to use scripts js in the mongo shell. I am reading a book on the topic. I have tried several options, such as opening the cmd at a specific place at my computer. 
I found here the question "How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?", but nothing seems to work for me. My mongo is working properly and I can enter mongo simply typing mongo at cmd. However, it cannot find the js files.
I am using Windows; anything has an idea what may be happening under the hood?

An example after:

```
mongo  demo.js

2020-02-20T11:03:33.098-0300 E  -        [main] file [demo.js] doesn't exist
2020-02-20T11:03:33.098-0300 F  -        [main] failed to load: demo.js
2020-02-20T11:03:33.098-0300 E  -        [main] exiting with code -3
```

Comment: The script file _should be in the same directory_ from where you are trying to run the above command.

Comment: yes I did that!

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: example, I want to use .mongorc.js, but it cannot find it even when it is placed in the proper directory.

Comment: Please tell what is there in the `demo.js`?

Comment: use sample  //db name
show collections

Comment: It is simple, I just want to show that works

Comment: I posted an answer with some examples; try them out and they will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208256/discussion-between-jorge-pires-and-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

Create your `my_script.js` file with this one command:

```
db.testColl.insertOne( { a: "hello" } )
```

Place the script file in your current directory.

**1. Run JS Script from OS Command-line:**

From OS prompt do this:

```
> mongo localhost/testDB my_script.js
```

Once the above command is run, you will see the output as follows (similar, depending upon your MongoDB version and the OS (Windows, in this case)):

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.3
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("456b350f-668f-4389-9901-7c456e2c50fe") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.3
```

Now, from the Mongo Shell (i.e., do `mongo`, and then from the *mongo* prompt):

```
mongo > use testDB
mongo > show collections
```

You will see the `testColl` listed.

```
mongo > db.testColl.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ea0d05816162b300b0346"), "a" : "hello" }
```

This is the document created in the `testDB` database and the collection `testColl` as per the command in the `my_script.js`.

**2. Run JS Script from Mongo Shell:**

Also, you can run the `my_script.js`from within the *Mongo Shell*.

```
mongo > load("my_script.js")
true
mongo > db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ea0d05816162b300b0346"), "a" : "hello" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ea10f276cde8fc5fedec5"), "a" : "hello" }
```

See there are two documents with different `_id` field values.

*NOTE:* I think you can run only some commands from the `.js` file.

**3. Another Example:**

Create a JS file named `script2.js` with the following content:

```
db.test.find().forEach(printjson)
```

Note the `printjson` shell method prints a document to the shell output.

```
mongo > load("script2.js")
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ea0d05816162b300b0346"), "a" : "hello" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ea10f276cde8fc5fedec5"), "a" : "hello" }
```

---

**References:**

- [load()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/index.html)
- [Print document value in
  MongoShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527617/print-document-value-in-mongodb-shell/57391433#57391433)