# Mongo commands not getting executed in Batch Script

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, automation

I am trying to execute a batch script to create a collection and insert data into it. It is opening Mongo.exe but it is not executing the commands.

I have tried the following ways.

```
cd  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe
mongo.exe --eval "use MyDatabase"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})"
pause
```

The above script opens Mongo.exe and does nothing other than that. I need help as I want to run every command in one connection with mongodb.
So I tried:

```
mongo.exe mydb D:\TFX\Delta\a.js
```

where a.js contains:

```
print(db)
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})
print(show collections)
print(db)
```

But after this it is showing that path of file D:\TFX\Delta\a.js not found (path of file is correct).

Comment: See this post: [How to execute mongo commands through shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322018/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts-mine-does-not-work/60323448#60323448).

Comment: not shell script,i need batch script example

Comment: @prasad_ do you know anyone who can help me ?

Comment: You can do a search as "mongodb mongo shell batch file", and you will get some results with similar issues.

Comment: @prasad_ i searched every possible websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running multiple calls to `mongo.exe` connections are distinct. You should give the database name at each call. You can use an `EOF` syntax or directly give it as a parameter in your command:

```
mongo.exe MyDatabase --eval "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})"
```

*EDIT:*

If you run it through a JS scripted file, you can run this:

```
mongo.exe commands.js
```

With a `commands.js` file like this:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB('MyDatabase')
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})
```

Comment: but i have username and password too, that also needed to be given multiple time

Comment: and on doing this multiple time the second command is throwing error, as the mongo is reconnecting, any solution for that ?

Comment: Yes you will have to give it multiple times. For username and password usage, you can still give it using `--username` and `--password` options. I really suggest you to put your mongo commands in a JS file and call it through `mongo.exe MyDatabase myfile.js`. This way you can do all your commands through an unique connection. What is the error you get while you say mongo is reconnecting? This should not be an issue to have multiple connections.

Comment: i don,t know how to write js file, can you write a sample file for me

Comment: like an example on my code above, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Syntax is described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo
See my edited message with an example for your implementation

Comment: thanks, but my file is not at same location, when i provide location it says file not found.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this: (program is according to azure devops pipeline)

```
FOR %%a IN (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO (
IF EXIST B:\agent\_work\%%a\Delta\script.txt (
cd /D C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
mongo --username abcd --password abcd --authenticationDatabase mydb mydb < B:\agent\_work\%%a\Delta\script.txt
goto break
)
)
:break
exit
```

where script.txt contains the commands to run on mongodb.